*very* simple examples for definite integrals, for programming and business students
I am teaching a precalculus and calculus class for students that have very few mathematical intuitions (but this question will probably benefit even more from the experience of high school calculus teachers, if they teach integrals)
We are arriving at definite integrals, and I need some examples of their usefulness
I have browsed the site for about 1 hour and a half, and saw some interesting examples, but that are not simple enough, unfortunately (eg: Activities for biology undergraduates taking integral calculus)
Keeping in mind that these are business and programming (not computer science, mind you!) students,
what are some very very simple examples of applications of the definite integral? Not that are easy to solve, that is not important, but such that it is easy to understand the problem.
I do not want, for example, to venture into probability density functions, that would be a natural application, because it requires too much context, too much extra content to understand the problem.
So far, I have exactly 1 example:

approximating a summation (ie: if company A has f(t) profit per year, how much have they amassed in 5 years)

I am looking for other very easy to understand questions. Preferably that have to do with images, image processing, machine learning (doubt that there is something there, in ML we seem to use mostly only derivatives) or some other very concrete example (pref. that does not require extra knowledge or, eg, physics)
To reiterate: the point of the question is not to have easy problems to solve but easy problems to understand the question . We'll mostly solve the integrals using Geogebra.

One interesting connection between definite integrals and digital images is "integration by pixel-counting". One can approximate the definite integral of a function (or the area of a circle) by drawing it, filling in the area under the curve, counting the pixels, and multiplying by the area of a pixel.

I need some examples of their usefulness What exactly does the word "usefulness" mean in this context?

What if you asked them for the formula for a cylinder? They don't know it, that's fine. Can you help them see it? (Not calculus yet.) If you can help them see why that one is true, then you can bring up cones. I don't believe there is an easy way to see why the formula has 1/3 in it without calculus.
But with calculus, it's easy.
To me, the benefit of this example for weak students is the focus on meaning. I would actually start by asking: What does the term 'area' mean? And then I'd  progress to volume, and have them figure out how many cubic foot boxes are needed to fill a box that's 2'x3'x4'.
Then we would do the cone, with infinitely thin disks. (Yeah, some people don't like that infinitely thin part. I do.)

I don't believe there is an easy way to see why the formula has 1/3 in it without calculus. The cube can be cut into three identical pyramids of height 1 and base of area 1; you can see them as "cones with square base". If only one believes in some basic principles of volume (e.g. the Cavalieri principle), then the volume of a cone doesn't depend on the base's shape but only its area; moreover, it depends linearly on the height. In consequence, we get the formula for volume of cones.

By the way, the same reasoning applies in any dimension, as you can cut the unit cube $[0,1]^n$ into $n$ pyramids given by $\max(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_i$ (where $i=1,\ldots,n$).  All of this said, I agree with you that calculus is the easy way to do it and may give the students some satisfaction.

Easiest works for me. (I do not think weak students would understand that the base's shape doesn't matter.)

not to have easy problems to solve but easy problems to understand the question
Preferably that have to do with images, image processing, machine learning
I'm not exactly sure why the "company profit" example you brought up as "the only one you have" is "easier to understand" than "Find the area under the parabola $y=x^2$ (and above the $x$-axis) from $-1$ to $2$" or what it has to do with images, image processing, or machine learning, so I may misinterpret your request quite a lot, but let me try  a couple nevertheless.

You have a complete aerial photograph of an irregularly shaped oil spill around a broken tanker (make some crude illustration yourself or find a real one on the web). The length of the tanker is known. What (approximately) is the total amount of spilled oil in liters? Assume the usual thickness of 1 mm for the oil film on water.

Get a good world map with clear latitude and longitude lines in the standard Mercator projection and notice that Greenland looks as large as the whole Europe, if not larger. Explain why that look is deceptive and how to set up an integral (with respect to the longitude or the latitude variable, your choice) to compute the true area of Greenland (or any other region on the map that looks interesting to you).


I'll stop here for now. If that is a good fit, I'll design a few more, but if I have completely misconstrued your request, just accept my apologies for wasting your time with this post :-)

1 mm??! It is at most 3$\mu$m! 3 microns, that is.

@user58697 Looks like you are right and I just confused $m$ with $\mu$ in the reference I took it from :-). Well, I'll just try to be more attentive next time.
